# VS 2017 Query Builder - Update query using 'where in'

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-update

I'm using Visual Studio's Query Builder to run an update command for possibly 1-2k updates using a single identifier. I'm trying to run it as a 'where in' command so its just one query running, rather than the db being peppered with 1-2k update commands.  I'm sure there are probably efficiency arguments between the two ways, but for me it just seems cleaner (thats a conversation for another day!)

However, I can't find any documentation on how to present the strings in the right format.  I've tried the below code with no joy.

```
UPDATE       ORDERS_TABLE
SET          PRINTED = 'Y', DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE        (ordercode IN (?))
```

When I test through using Execute Query the Value's I've tried have been:

```
"A12", "A44"
'A12','A44'
 A12, A44
 A12;A44;
```

So far I've had no success.  Is it even possible?

Comment: The 2nd one is correct - lose the brackets around the clause, and just have them around the list:     WHERE ordercode IN ('A12','A44')

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: Ok, thanks for your quick reply. So if I remove the brackets around the clause I get a 'Missing subquery or the operator you entered requires parenthesis. Error in list of values in IN clause.
Unable to parse query text.' message.

Comment: I love the easy way queries can be created in the Query Builder, but sadly some of the actual construction of the query is not best.

Comment: @SeanR, Sorry, my question may not be overly clear.  I'm fine with the syntax of how to do an update query if i was executing it withing sql studio for example, but this is constructing it within the Query Builder of Visual Studio.  Regardless of how I pass the string to the tableadapter, it either only updates the first ordercode or none at all.